# How to check the presence of php and apache on ubuntu server through ssh

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, ssh

How can I check whether apache is installed with php and mysql on Ubuntu server through ssh?

Also if it is installed, in which directory?

And if in case some other package is installed, like lighttpd, where that is.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Type `aptitude` to start the package manager. There you can see which applications are installed.

Use `/` to search for packages. Try searching for `apache2` and `php5` (or whatever versions you want to use). If they are installed, they should be bold and have an `i` in front of them. If they are not installed (`p` in front of the line) and you want to install them (and you have root permissions), use `+` to select them and then `g` (twice) to install it.

Word of warning: Before doing that, it might be wise to have a quick look at some *aptitude* tutorial on the web.

Comment: It shows perl python etc but not php and apache does this mean it is not installed?

Comment: See above, I've extended my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot apache was not installed. I will find some tutorial on setting up a ubuntu server

Answer (score 46):

Another way to find out if a program is installed is by using the `which` command. It will show the path of the program you're searching for. For example if when your searching for apache you can use the following command:

```
$ which apache2ctl
/usr/sbin/apache2ctl
```

And if you searching for PHP try this:

```
$ which php
/usr/bin/php
```

If the `which` command doesn't give any result it means the software is not installed (or is not in the current `$PATH`):

```
$ which php
$
```

Comment: theres no response when i try this

Comment: That means that those programs are not installed or are called by a different name. But if you use Ubuntu, this should work. Also if the first one (for apache) doesn't work, probably the second also won't work.

Comment: I think this easy and best way thaks @PeterStuifzand

Answer (score 14):

**How to tell on Ubuntu if apache2 is running:**

```
sudo service apache2 status

/etc/init.d/apache2 status

ps aux | grep apache
```

Answer (score 6):

You could inspect the available apache2 modules:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/apache2/modules/
```

Or try to enable the php module, if you have the appropriate access:

```
$ a2enmod
Which module would you like to enable?
Your choices are: actions alias asis ...
... php5 proxy_ajp proxy_balancer proxy_connect ..
```

Comment: After trying this i get no such file or directory

Comment: This means apache2 is not installed. Use sudo aptitude install apache2 to install it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
dpkg -s apache2 | grep Status 

dpkg -s php5 | grep Status
```